# Как из многострочного текста вытянуть значение python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, строки, list

У меня есть большой массив текста со значениями , к примеру План - 200 , факт - 300. Нужно чтобы программа распознавала слово "План" и возвращала значение 200 в переменную plan[] списком

далее для наглядности как это будет выглядеть:

```
artem = input('Введите Ваш отчет: ')
semen = input('Введите Ваш отчет: ')
kolya = input('Введите Ваш отчет: ')

def plan(x):
    if 'План' in x:
        plan[200] #Мне нужно чтобы в этот список попадало значение Плана из строки (оно может быть разным)

plan(artem)
plan(semen)
plan(kolya)

def kalkulator (a,b,c,d,e):
    return a + b + c + d + e

print(kalkulator(plan))
```

#отчет будет прилетать из вне в виде скопированного сообщения из вайбера вот в таком виде одним сообщением через энтер

> План - 200
> Факт- 216

> Напитки план-10
> Напитки факт-4

> Визиты - 20
> Заказы - 19

> Эффективность - 95%
> x - 9.9

> w -3,5

> q -4,5

> gop - 44,16

#так же столкнулся с ошибкой что так как текст написан через энтер при ctl-c  ctrl-v терминал распознает только первую строчку

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Не называйте имена переменных именами функций, иначе питон будет их путать**
2. Я предложу свой вариант решения, только формат записи должен быть в едином варианте. Если вы пишите, что входными данными могут быть: `word - word word- wors`, `Word-Word\nword-word`, то придержитесь одного, например: `word- word\nword - word`, или если одна пара: `word-word`.

```
artem = input('Введите Ваш отчет: ') '''План - 200
Факт - 216''' 

semen = input('Введите Ваш отчет: ') '''
План - 500
Факт- 219
Напиток-300
'''
kolya = input('Введите Ваш отчет: ') '''План - 200''' 

plan_list = []


def plan(x):
    if 'План' in x:
        for val in x.split('\n'):
                if val.split('-')[0].strip() == 'План':
                    plan_list.append(int(val.split('-')[1].strip()))
                    
    return plan_list


plan(artem)
plan(semen)
plan(kolya)

print(sum(plan_list)) # можно так(сумма значений в списке) 

def kalkulator(vals): # можно так(через функцию) 
    sum_nums = 0
    for num in vals:
        sum_nums += num
    return sum_nums


print(kalkulator(plan_list))
```

Вывод:

```
900
900
```

Comment: @maudzydun Если вам ответ устроил, пожалуйста, оцените его голосом